How to reduce the length of Horizontal Rule from right side only in HTML
I am trying to reduce the length/width of horizontal rule from right side only but when I did it using CSS stylesheet the length reduced from both the side.
I want that its length reduce from right side only. Please help me to solve the problem

I think you do it by putting the <hr> inside a <div> and then set the width of the div.

An hr has a default margin left/right of auto so you can just adjust that and then set a width.


  hr {
  border-color: red;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 0;
<hr>



